# What to install to run oracle commands

Tags: sql, database, oracle, osx-snow-leopard

In database class we were to type the following commands in SQL

```
CREATE TABLE extensions (
extension number(5) PRIMARY KEY,
department VARCHAR(20) );
CREATE TABLE employee (
SSN NUMBER(9) PRIMARY KEY,
extension NUMBER(5) references extensions,
name VARCHAR2(20),
salary number(10, 2) check (salary >= 0) not null,
startdate date
);
```

I was able to do this using sqlite3 in OSX.

Now I'm supposed to do the same thing using Oracle instead of SQL. I've tried installing a number of things, but can't get it to work.

What should I install.

Comment: Are you trying to install an Oracle database on your OS X machine?  Or are you trying to connect to a remote Oracle database (installed on a university server or on another machine in your network) from your OS X machine?

Comment: I'm not trying to connect to a remote database. I'm just trying to get practice on using the syntax by doing things like creating database tables and inserting table entries.

Comment: You need to connect to a database to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle no longer supports running the Oracle database on OS X.  Oracle did support running a database on Apple machines some time ago but Oracle doesn't generally make old versions of the database available for download.  There is a version of [Oracle 10.2.0.4  for Mac OS X on Intel x86-64](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/10204macsoft-x86-64-092720.html) that is still available for download on OTN. Do you happen to be running OS X on Intel x86-64?

If you don't happen to be running OS X on Intel x86-64, you could set up a virtual machine on your OS X box that is running an operating system that Oracle does support (Linux or Windows most likely) and install Oracle there.

Answer (score 0):

You need oracle server. download for mac here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/10204macsoft-x86-64-092720.html